# Merging of two functions

Tags: code-optimization

This is my Arduino code that checks the water Level of two different water reservoirs via 2 water Level Sensors A and B:

```
#define Water_Level_A 5;
#define Water_Level_B 6;

boolean Water_Level_Check_A(){
boolean Result = digitalRead(Water_Level_A);
return Result;
}
boolean Water_Level_Check_B(){
boolean Result = digitalRead(Water_Level_B);
return Result;
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(Water_Level_A,INPUT);
    pinMode(Water_Level_B,INPUT);
    }

void loop() {
if (Water_Level_Check_A() == LOW){
--> Water Pump A
}
if Water_Level_Check_B() == LOW{
--> Water Pump B
}
```

What's the best way to simplify this code so that I only need one `Water_Level_Check` function so that the distinction between A and B and Water_Level_A and Water_Level_B is made within the function and the loop part looks like this:

```
void loop() {
if (Water_Level_Check_(A) == LOW){
--> Water Pump A 
}
if Water_Level_Check_(B) == LOW{
--> Water Pump B
}
```

Comment: How about giving the function the pin number to read from as a parameter? In this case you would write `if(Water_Level_Check(Water_Level_A) == LOW)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is something like this:

```
boolean Water_Level_Check(uint8_t level_pin){
   boolean Result = digitalRead(pin);
   if( level_pin == Water_Level_A ){
      // manage pump A here
   }
   else if( level_pin == Water_Level_B ){
      // manage pump B here
   }
   else {
      Serial.println("Water_Level_Check: unknown pin number.");
      // or some other way of dealing with a bad-pin-number bug.
      return -1;
   }

   return Result;
}
```

for the level testing function, which will simplify you loop function to:

```
void loop() {
   (void)Water_Level_check(Water_Level_A);
   (void)Water_Level_check(Water_Level_B);
}
```

The `(void)` expression before each call is a "cast to void", telling the the compiler to consider the function's boolean return value to have been intentionally "voided", i.e. you *intended* not to read it, and not to give an error message.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like

```
boolean Water_Level_Check_A(){
   boolean Result = digitalRead(Water_Level_A);
   return Result;
}
```

Are really overcomplicated. You're just calling one function and returning that value, so it can be simplified to

```
boolean Water_Level_Check_A(){
   return digitalRead(Water_Level_A);
}
```

Or just the expression

```
digitalRead(Water_Level_A)
```

whenever you need it.

So all you're doing is calling `digitalRead()` on a pin number and check if the result is low. If you really want to move this to a different function then you could give it the pin number argument and directly invert the result so that a `true` from this function means that some action needs to be done.

```
boolean Water_Level_Check(int sensorPin){
   return !digitalRead(sensorPin);
}
```

And then call it as

```
void loop() {
   if (Water_Level_Check(Water_Level_A)){
       //--> Water Pump A
   }
   if (Water_Level_Check(Water_Level_B )){
       //--> Water Pump B
   }
}
```

Comment: The `boolean Water_Level_Check_A()` I'm using in my code also includes the Powering On and OFF of the Water Level Sensor. That's why I used the function in the first place. The code here is just the minimal example for my question on how to change A and B in the function. The `return !digitalRead(sensorPin)` looks cleaner than my approach :-) Thanks